# IIS performance benefits of multiple sites for the same application

Tags: iis, performance

We run a single application off of a single IIS 7.5 instance.  Are there performance benefits to running that application as several sites on that instance?  e.g.  www01.mysite.com, www02.mysite.com, etc.  Are there particular pitfalls to this approach?

I haven't been able to find many references to this type of setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume you are lazy and thus write "application" instead of "application pool".

Less overhead, less processes. OTOH you have the 2gb limit (unless you switch the pol to 64 bit, which is against MS best practices).

The main advantage is that one application restart restarts all of them.

The performance benefit is - seriously low.

So, no - not in the practical sense.

Comment: The use of "application" vs. "application pool" was intentional as I think -- perhaps wrongly -- that the use of one or more application pools is an implementation detail with its own set of implications.  I was thinking that each site would have its own application pool and benefit from a dedicated process while avoiding web garden challenges around session state, etc.  I wouldn't want a process recycling to necessarily recycle every other site and thus lose cache, etc.

Comment: Not really, as an application is a logical construct (session etc.) and you can map multiple applications to the same application pool. The critical change is rather the pool, not the application.